# Neo4j 4.0 Define APOC custom procedure

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-apoc

I'm using Neo4j 4.0.3 Community (with Docker), apoc-4.0.0.7-all.jar and have a problem when calling APOC custom procedure.
Here is the code, which works with Neo4j 3.5.17.

Am I missing something in the new version?

```
// Create Nodes and relationship
CREATE (p1:Person {name: 'Paul'})-[:DRIVES]->(c1:Car {name: 'Car A'}) ;

// Define procedure
CALL apoc.custom.asProcedure('Test',
"WITH { CarName: $CarName } as params
MATCH (c:Car)
WHERE c.name = params.CarName
RETURN c
;", 'read',
[['c','Node']], [['CarName','STRING']],  'Display car node') ;

// Call procedure
CALL custom.Test('Car A') ;
```

The error is the following when calling the procedure:

```
Neo.DatabaseError.General.UnknownError
[Node[1]:org.neo4j.kernel.impl.core.NodeEntity] is not a supported property value
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Fyi, I raised an issue: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/1498